# Sin in GNU Octave plotted has pointy edges

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, octave, trigonometry

What is the problem in this code?

Why is it not a normal sin curve?

Is there a better way to take 1000 samples of the sin curve in GNU Octave?

```
t = (0:1/1003:1);
A=4;
x=A*sin(2*pi*80*t);
axis([0,100,-4,4])
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: TIL sinus is not a joke math word...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a smoother curve, you'll need to plot more points.  Try reducing the timestep, by increasing the `1003` value.

Comment: Yeah, 1003/80 is about 12.5 data points per wavelength.  Not a lot.

Comment: one more question 80 is referring to MHz? or can be?

Comment: @trinny: Well, it could be, but I have no idea whether it actually is!  It's your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just the sample-rate, you need a higher one.  :) - this is the funniest thing I've read for a while.

Think of it as blocky or pixelated but for vectors. You need a higher 'resolution'.